# Possible ways to pronounce an IPv6 address

Tags: numbers, internet

When reading out IPv4 addresses, people typically say something like, "ten dot one dot seven" etc. This is pretty easy since "dot" is one syllable. How can IPv6 addresses be pronounced? Saying "colon" over and over is just awkward.

Comment: You'd rather say "large intestine"?

Comment: In Japanese, separated series of numbers, whether divided by periods, colons or hyphens, are all separated by の (no), which is roughly equivalent to the English " 's " construction. If your house number is 1-20-5, you'd read that as 1's 20's 5, which is perfectly logical. In English, a pause would serve that purpose equally well. Since your IPv6 address is broken neatly into 4-character chunks, I would offer that the easiest way to read them would be rhythmically, pausing at the colons. "F10C...D238...A1A9..."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure who you're reading your IP addresses to, but skipping the punctuation is very common in IPv4 and it only makes sense in IPv6.

For instance, in IPv4, 192.168.1.1 is frequently read: "one ninety two one sixty eight one *dot* one". The last dot is pronounced since it separates two 1 numbers, whereas the others aren't read because they're redundant.

The same is true for IPv6, but the separators are *always* redundant. Every IPv6 has the same number of characters, so just read the ones that matter.

However, it's usually easier to copy/paste them into a text message or some other non-audio format.

Comment: When you use the abbreviated notation, an IPv6 address loses characters where there is a string of binary zeroes. Therefore the colons are not redundant. How would you say 2001:db8:3c4d:15::1a2f:1a2b

Comment: You could say the implicit zeroes, or you could read the colons that follow a shortened segment. I still think I would lean towards a text message or email.

Comment: Punctuation in IPv6 is not redundant. 1a:1a:1a:1a:: is different than 1a1a:1a1a::, but using your solution both would be pronounced exactly the same.

Comment: @BenPiper that was already noted by Godwin. I responded to him. If this is not satisfactory, perhaps you could agree on a monosyllabic delimiter with the person to whom you are reading the IPv6 address. For example, you could decide that "n" is suitable since it never appears in an address. "1an1an1an1ann" vs "1a1an1a1ann".